# Ionic 4 custom components

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

How do you load a component in ionic 4 after running the command `ionic g component myComponent`? I want to add a new generated custom component to my home page.

Comment: I actually have the exactly same issue, it's quite easy to reproduce as well. Just start a new project: ionic start project blank --type=angular.
Then generate a component: ionic g component timer
And finally add <app-timer></app-timer> to home.page.html

It'll give you the "app-timer is not a known element" error.

I've read through a lot of the v4 documentation to no avail.

I realize this doesn't solve it, but I thought I'd provide a repro.

EDIT: line breaks are missing, sorry about that.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Finally figured this out, here's a repro that works:

```
ionic start myProject blank --type=angular
ionic g module components
ionic g component components/myComponent --export
```

This adds both a declaration and export to the components module for "myComponent".

To use the component just add `ComponentsModule` to your `imports` in your page module, e.g.

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path: '',
            component: HomePage
        }
    ])
],
declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

This way nothing is added to `app.module.ts` which is how it should be.

Also note if you want to use ANY  components in your own custom components, you need to add `IonicModule` to the `imports` in `components.module.ts`

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Somehow, it works with a blank new project, but in my existing project it loads an empty page with no errors reported.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found this very helpful

Comment: If i want to use single component in any page..? Then also do i need to import whole componentModule to my page module?

Comment: For some reason, the --export flag didn't work for me, but adding the MyComponentComponent to the ComponentsModule declarations and exports arrays manually worked.

Comment: With the comment from glmdev it works, but in the html the component shows "element not found". After I added the myComponent to EntryComponents in home.module.ts it works for me.

Answer (score 26):

Basically, `ionic g component myComponent` will update the app.module.ts and create the component inside the app folder.

But if you want a more elegant way to add the components. Here is the steps:

```
ionic g module components
```

will generate a module folder called `components`. Then generate a bunch of components:

```
ionic g component components/myComponent --export
ionic g component components/myComponent2 --export
ionic g component components/myComponent3 --export
ionic g component components/myComponent4 --export
```

Inside components.module.ts could be write like this :

```
...
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MyComponentComponent } from './my-component/my-component.component';
import { MyComponentComponent2 } from './my-component2/my-component2.component';
import { MyComponentComponent3 } from './my-component3/my-component3.component';
import { MyComponentComponent4 } from './my-component4/my-component4.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponentComponent,
    MyComponentComponent2,
    MyComponentComponent3,
    MyComponentComponent4
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MyComponentComponent,
    MyComponentComponent2,
    MyComponentComponent3,
    MyComponentComponent4
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

and then make sure to import the components module inside the `app.module.ts`:

```
...
import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    ...
    ComponentsModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

To test the components, you need to create a page or component again.

```
ionic g page testing
```

Import components module into your testing component/page or (into your current home page similarly):

```
...
import { ComponentsModule } from '../components/components.module';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
     ...
     ComponentsModule,
     ...
  ],
  declarations: [TestingPage]
})
export class TestingPageModule {}
```

Finally, just write the component inside the testing page by using the component selector. e.g.

```
<app-my-component></app-my-component>
<app-my-component2></app-my-component2>
<app-my-component3></app-my-component3>
<app-my-component4></app-my-component4>
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: Really great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

This is your selector in components>foot-card>foot-card.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'foot-card',
  templateUrl: 'foot-card.html'
})
export class FootCardComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello FootCardComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}
```

This is your components.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FootCardComponent } from './foot-card/foot-card';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [FootCardComponent],
    imports: [IonicModule],
    exports: [FootCardComponent]
})

export class ComponentsModule {}
```

This is your app.module.ts:

```
import { FootCardComponent } from '../components/foot-card/foot-card';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../components/components.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    FootCardComponent
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You have to import component-module in import and declare component-name in entry components in app.module.ts.

In components.module.ts, You have to declare and export the component but don't forget to import IonicModule.

I was facing the same problem but no one told to import IonicModule In Components.module.ts and In app.module.ts, only add to entryComponent and import componentModule.

Answer (score 7):

After doing all the above ...

only worked in home.page.html
adding **app** before the name of my component like :

```
<app-my-component></app-my-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to include a new module, specifically for your custom component.

I just do not understand why the command "ionic generate component components/myComponent --export" no longer creates this outmoded module. I went through this same [problem here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-adding-a-custom-component-to-ionic-4/156744/5).

Answer (score 1):

Testes this solution on Ionic 6.11.0. Works perfectly.
Flows to create a reusable component named 'FeaturedProduct' -

Step 1: Create a component `ionic g component components/FeaturedProduct`

Step 2: Create a module for this component.
`ionic g module components/FeaturedProduct`

Step 3: Import FeaturedProductComponent to featured-product.module.ts file

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [FeaturedProductComponent],
  exports: [FeaturedProductComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
```

Step 4: Import FeaturedProductModule on the module.ts file of your desired page.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ...
    FeaturedProductModule
  ],
  declarations: [Tab2Page]
})
```

Now the component can be used by this tag
`<app-featured-product></app-featured-product>`

Answer (score 0):

### In your src/components folder

**myComponent.html**:

```
//Here your component HTML Code. For example:
<ion-list radio-group (ionSelect)="change($event, item.type);" 
  ... 
</ion-list>
```

**components.module.ts**:

```
import {myComponentComponent} from "./myComponent/myComponent";
@NGModule({
  declatations: [myComponentComponent],
  imports:[],
  exports: [myComponentComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule{}
```

### In your src/app folder

**app.module.ts**:

```
import { MyComponentComponent } from "../components/myComponent/myComponent";

@NGModule({
   declarations: [
      yourPages....,
     MyComponentComponent
   ]
)}
```

### To use it:

For example in **HomePage.html**:

```
<myComponent> </myComponent>
```

Comment: 'mycomponent' is not a known element:
1. If 'mycomponent' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Comment: I forgot components.module.ts

Comment: i guess you wil have to edit the app.module.ts  declarations to

Comment: Yes as in my Answer. There I described what to do in app.module.ts

Comment: no please note that in ionic 4 its proving to be difficult try doing it

Comment: I dont think that there is a different component installation in Ionic 4 than in Ionic 3. What is now the problem?

Comment: Jonathan > Ionic 4 doesn't handle components the same way as Ionic 3. Your solution works fine for Ionic 3, but not for Ionic 4.

Answer (score 0):

simply enter below command to genrate custom component

**ionic g component components/Component-Name**

add component to html